# DefaultRetryPolicy - write timeout

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

The documentation for `DefaultRetryPolicy` says that

> This policy retries queries in only two cases:
>
> On a read timeout, if enough replicas replied but data was not retrieved. 
>   **On a write timeout, if we timeout while writing the
>   distributed log used by batch statements.** This retry policy is
>   conservative in that it will never retry with a different consistency
>   level than the one of the initial operation.

Does this mean that when I do a simple `session.execute(BoundStatement)` without using any custom retry policy and get a write time out that the default retry policy will kick in and there will be a retry to write the data again ? What does the "distributed log used by batch statements" mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify any specific retry policy , driver will use DefaultRetryPolicy

By default, Retry on write timeout in applicable for Logged Batch operation  (logged batch enforces atomicity).

no retry will happen on write timeout in case of non batch operation